# Unable to push to git repository on windows server 2016

Tags: windows, git, windows-server-2016

I have a windows server 2016 where i have setup ssh (using openssh) and a git repository, 'restserver.git' (using `git init --bare`)

The full path to the git repo/folder is C:/repo/restserver.git

I can successfully connect to my server through ssh. see screenshot below

[image]

After setting up my local repo and trying to push like this:

```
mkdir localrepo 
cd localrepo
git init
//creates a file
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add server ssh://root@ipaddress/repo/restserver.git
git push server master
```

i get the following error:

[image]

I noticed that When i ssh into the server, i am at the C:\Users{username} directory

Also i have tried creating the git repo at C:\Users{username}\repo\restserver.git, but i still get the same error.

I also followed the steps taken in this tutorial https://medium.com/@praveen_vijayan/setting-up-git-post-hook-for-automated-deployments-mac-windows-server-cdd8f7bb7200

Comment: `ssh root@ipaddress` and verify that `/repo/restserver.git` is available.

Comment: Hi @phd , it exists under C:/repo/restserver.git

Comment: Try URL `ssh://root@ipaddress/c/repo/restserver.git`

Comment: I got error “could not resolve hostname  ipaddress/c/repo/restserver.git: No such host is known.”

Comment: `ssh://root@ipaddress/repo/restserver.git` works (host/ip resolved and connected) but `ssh://root@ipaddress/c/repo/restserver.git` doesn't? Hard to believe…

Comment: ssh://root@ipaddress/repo/restserver.git does not work too. Only this works : ssh://root@ipaddress and it takes me to the root directory which is c:\Users\cspcloudadmin